# How to use dynamic connection string in mongodbcontext in C#

Tags: mongodb

I would like to connect to the database specified in the connection string. I have multiple connection strings for different client and multiple database in one cluster

```
 public MongoContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;

        // Every command will be stored and it'll be processed at SaveChanges
        _commands = new List<Func<Task>>();
    }



    private void ConfigureMongo()
    {
        if (MongoClient != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Configure mongo (You can inject the config, just to simplify)
        MongoClient = new MongoClient(_configuration["MongoSettings:Connection"]);

        Database = MongoClient.GetDatabase(_configuration["MongoSettings:DatabaseName"]);
    }
public IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>(string name)
            {
                ConfigureMongo();

                return Database.GetCollection<T>(name);
            }
  
}
```

For each request, i want to set connection string dynamically based on UserID

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've got what you're asking, but if you need connecting to more than one cluster, you should create a separate mongo client for each separate cluster